# NetBeans - How to Build Project jar file with all required libraries

Tags: java, jar, netbeans6.5

I've tried to build my project with NetBeans 6.5; The thing is the project contains external jars added so I need them all being placed into my jar file (because it is to be signed); but IDE just places project classes in the jar :(

So my question is how to place project dependent external libs into my project JAR with NetBeans ?

Comment: When I faced this problem I decided to use Ant (it's not really complicated and gives you freedom to choose what the structure would be). What do you mean saying "signed"? I was told once about the option of putting libraries in the `dist/lib` folder of the project (I don't remember if NetBeans should do that or a developer), this should work.

Comment: I want to have all libs' dependent classes to be included automatically  in a single jar. Is it possible not to use Ant for this?

Comment: Why not use ant? NB uses ant itself and if you want it automatically it's your best bet as @JohnDoe answer shows. Even the signing can be done with ant.

Comment: Because I want to achieve the effect with IDE. Something like JBuilder does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like [this fat jar tutorial](http://arunasujith.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-build-fat-jar-using-netbeans.html). I'm not sure if it's easier than building with an Ant script, but it should do the trick.

Comment: Netbeans is already using Ant to build projects (unless they are Maven projects). This is adding tasks to the regular ant structure of NB.

Comment: This adds signing the jar: http://ezzatron.com/2009/09/29/automatically-signing-jar-files-in-netbeans/

Comment: @madth3 I know, you're right. I'm not sure if adding tasks to the regular Ant structure of NetBeans is a more comfortable decision than using Ant without the IDE.

Comment: @John Doe, thanks :) I guess this is it. Because I did wanted to make the jar with IDE anyway