# How to make a monolithic jar.file?

Tags: java, hadoop

I need to create a hadoop job jar file that uses mahout and a bunch of other libraries. I need ti be able to run the job without needing additional jar.files such that all referenced classes are packaged with the resultant jar file. How can this be done?

Comment: Are you talking about a fat jar? It's not really hard to do this with an Ant. Here is the discussion on how to build such a jar in NetBeans: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745885/netbeans-how-to-build-project-jar-file-with-all-required-libraries/9746340#9746340

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your build file to copy all the referenced classes to the build directory. For example, in `ant`:

```
    <path id="classpathunjar">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" excludes="sqljdbc4.jar"/>
    </path>


    <target name="compile" depends="clean">
        ...
        <unjar dest="${build.dir}">
            <path refid="classpathunjar" />
        </unjar>
        ...
   </target>
```

But it is better if you can manage without doing this. Use the `libjars` feature to load the jars into all nodes if you are doing this for running mapreduce jobs on a hadoop cluster

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop has the ability to read jars-in-jar. Amend you Ant script to include all the dependency jars in a folder called lib, and add this lib folder to your output Jar. This is sometimes a better choice if you have number of larger jars as it decreases your jar build time.

See this article on a number of options you have when using 3rd party libs with hadoop

- http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/

Answer (score 1):

`Jar` is just a `Zip` container.

You can manually unzip and modify your `Jar` file with the classes needed, or you can make use of e.g., the [jar-with-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor.html) descriptor of the [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) build system.

Answer (score 1):

In the generic sense, it is sometimes impossible, as JAR files have resources that must be in particular locations, and two conflicting but necessary resources might prevent the combination (Think META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)

However, in many cases it is very easy.  Basically you unzip the JAR file to be added (it is a zip file format) and "add" the classes and what-not to the existing JAR file.

A better choice if you are making an executable JAR file is to add a ClassPath entry into your launching MANIFEST.MF and ship both JAR files in a directory structure compatible with your added ClassPath entry.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the additional jars have to be put under a lib/ subdirectory (Yes, jars within a jar). I use the following maven assembly, which I found somewhere else.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
  <id>job</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <unpack>false</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core</exclude>
        <exclude>${artifact.groupId}:${artifact.artifactId}</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </dependencySet>
    <dependencySet>
      <unpack>false</unpack>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>${artifact.groupId}:${artifact.artifactId}</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${basedir}/target/classes</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory> 
      <excludes>
        <exclude>*.jar</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```