# How to run multiple java files at once?

Tags: hadoop, cloud

I have multiple .java files for my hadoop project. How do I execute them without using eclipse?

PS: I use the default ubuntu terminal

Answer (score 1):

You can use javac *.java to compile all the files in the current working directory.  As for executing them, use java *filename*
Where the filename does NOT have the .class at the end.  IE, you have `MyProgram.java` which compiles into `MyProgram.class` you would type: `java MyProgram`

You want the run the main class of your project btw (slightly vague, but it might be the only one with a main method).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [compile](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-33.htm) your `.java` files into a jar and then use the hadoop [jar](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/commands_manual.html#jar) command to execute it.  If your code has external dependencies, you will need to either use the `-libjars` flag or create a [fat jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9829583/698839).

Comment: I linked how to do so with Eclipse, but here is an example for how to do so with Ant:
http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html#four-steps

Answer (score 0):

Following is the simple steps for compiling hadoop java files and executing programs:

Compile:

javac -classpath < HADOOP_INSTALL_DIR>/hadoop-< Version>.jar -d < OUTPUT_DIR_NAME> ( < YOUR_MUTLIPLE_JAVAFILES_PATH> --like *.java)

Build jar file:

jar cvf < YOUR_JAR_FILE_PATH_WITH_NAME> -C <(previous compiled output)OUTPUT_DIR_NAME>

Run Hadoop program using Hadoop Jar command:

hadoop jar < JAR_FILE_PATH> < MAIN_PROGRAM_NAME_IN_JAR> < INPUT_PARAMETERS_IF-ANY>

Hope this helps!